# print a 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I trained to write a 2d array and then I dont know how to complete , pls help me
here is the code (it's simple) :

```
family = [
    ['zak','mikle','lion','sonia','Richard'],
    [14 , 12 , 11 , 47 , 48],
    ['moh','pr','el noob','lala','pa'],
    ['deep','lovly','noob','kind','smart'],

],
print(family[1][1])
```

and here is the problem :

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `,` at the end of the `family` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the extra comma after the end of your array:

```
family = [
    ['zak','mikle','lion','sonia','Richard'],
    [14 , 12 , 11 , 47 , 48],
    ['moh','pr','el noob','lala','pa'],
    ['deep','lovly','noob','kind','smart'],

]
print(family[1][1])
```